# Does ISP know I have an onion server if I set up a onion website at home?

Tags: onion-routing, website, server

I wanna set up a onion server at home . But does  my ISP know that ??

Answer (score 1):

It is generally easy for an ISP to tell that you're connecting to the Tor network. Tor onion service traffic looks similar to Tor client proxy traffic, so it shouldn't be immediately obvious to your ISP that you're running an onion service (compared to acting as a Tor client). They may be able to infer it's an onion service based on traffic patterns. For example, web servers typically send much more data than they receive, so if they observe that you're sending large amounts of traffic to the Tor network, they may assume you're running an onion service. Using a bridge may help hide that you're accessing the Tor network.

So to answer your question: yes they can (or they can at least infer it), but it depends on if they're actively looking for people running onion services.

Comment: i guess the concern wouldn't be about the active monitoring of clients running onion websites, but the possibility of the ISP being served a warrant to trace that onion site to one of their clients. If your answer is yes to the question, this means that running an onion site from home does not provide anonymity and that it instead must be created and maintained at non-home locations, other peoples' servers. cloud servers?

Comment: The ISP can't tell *what* onion site you're running, they can only make an informed guess about whether you're running some onion service or not. And this requires the ISP to be actively logging and monitoring traffic patterns.